# IDXGISwapChain can't present in window sub portion, or a sub rectangle?

Tags: directx-11, dxgi

d3d9 can present to a subrect by paramater.
but cann't found any way in d3d11.
even create swap chain in sub portion in window , swapchain fill all window.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following link on writing a good question and edit accordingly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Direct3D 9 swapchain only supported destination rectangles when using `D3DSWAPEFFECT_COPY` mode. This was not a particularly common or efficient usage pattern.

DXGI-based swapchains are associated with a full presentation window. DXGI 1.2 (DirectX 11.1) added the ability to specify dirty-rectangles when calling `Present1` if using the `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_SEQUENTIAL` swap effect mode.

[Enhancing presentation with the flip model, dirty rectangles, and scrolled areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706345.aspx)

> It would be helpful to specify what it is you are trying to actually achieve here.

Comment: Present1 can present to sub region,  but first time cann't specify dirty-rectangles. else error:Partial Presentation (using scroll or dirty rects) is not valid until first submitting a regular Present without scroll or dirty rects. Otherwise, the preserved back-buffer data would be uninitialized. [ MISCELLANEOUS ERROR #105: ];     so Present1 also overwrite window's gdi content